# sequelize get data from three tables

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

Currently I have three related tables in one, users, roles and events. I need to get the users of an event and the roles of each one in the same json

I made the relationship in the database and in the API

```
db.role.belongsToMany(db.user, {
  through: "user_roles_evento",
  foreignKey: "rolId",
  otherKey: "userId"
});

db.user.belongsToMany(db.role, {
  through: "user_roles_evento",
  foreignKey: "userId",
  otherKey: "rolId"
});
```

But I can't get the result I want.
The result I need to obtain is the following:

```
{
"users": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "maurigarri3@gmail.com",
        "name": "Mauricio",
        "lastname": "Garrido",
        "avatar": null,
        "event": {
                "id": 50,
                "desc": "History Class"
             }
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name" : "admin"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name" : "teacher"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Please show the associations for `events`